# How to use Mono's content in Reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to call a reactive REST API to fetch deadlinesTS variable.
Then I'm trying to set the same in my Pojo class.
But the value after setting the deadlineTS in BOLCompliance is not consistent using subscribe(). Sometimes I'm able to set the value, other times I get null. How can I make sure everytime I'm able to set the value.

```
Mono<String> deadlineTS = portCallServiceCaller.getDeadlineTSByComplianceId(compliance.getId());

BOLCompliance complianceResponse = new BOLCompliance();
deadlineTS.subscribe(val->complianceResponse.setDeadlineTimestamp(val));
```

Comment: @lkatiforis: please answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Mono's content outside a reactive pipeline (blocking)

You can use `block()` method like this:

```java
Mono<String> nameMono = Mono.just("some-value").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(300));

Person person = new Person();
person.setName(nameMono.block());

System.out.println(person.getName());
```

This triggers the operation and waits for its completion. Note that the calling thread blocks.

Alternatively, you could use [subscribe(consumer, errorConsumer, completeConsumer)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) and provide a `Runnable` that will be triggered when the operation is completed:

```
valueMono.subscribe(v-> person.setName(v), throwable -> {}, () -> System.out.println(person.getName()));
```

However, the `subscribe()` method will return immediately.

### Use Mono's content within a reactive pipeline

You can choose one of the operators provided depending on the case.

In this case, you can use `map` operator to transform the `String` into `BOLCompliance`:

```java
  Mono<BOLCompliance> fetchBOLCompliance() {
    Mono<String> deadlineMono = portCallServiceCaller.getDeadlineTSByComplianceId(compliance.getId();

    return deadlineMono.map(deadline -> {
      BOLCompliance compliance = new BOLCompliance();
      compliance.setDeadlineTimestamp(deadline);
      return compliance;
    });
  }
```

If you would like to run an asynchronous task (eg. database access) you would need to use `flatmap` operator.

### subscribe() returns immediately

According to [Javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-):

`Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer)`

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will
> immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the
> impression the consumer is not invoked when executing in a main thread
> or a unit test for instance.

In other words, the subscribe method kicks odd the work and returns immediately. So you get no guarantee that the operation is done. For instance, the following example will always end up with a null value:

```java
Mono<String> nameMono = Mono.just("some-value").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(300));

Person person = new Person();
nameMono.subscribe(v-> person.setName(v));

System.out.println(person.getName());
```

Here, the `person.getName()` method is invoked immediately while `person.setName(v)` is invoked after 300 milliseconds.

Comment: If I use block(), I'm getting this error - block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor, how to fix now?

Comment: Edit made. You should never use `block()` within a reactive pipeline.

Comment: @MiraDevi Does this work for you? If it answers your question then please consider upvoting the answer and accept it as correct so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions.

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry for not upvoting it as I was thinking the person who asked the question, his upvote doesn't count. Thanks a lot for the solution.