# How to return int value from Mono in reactive programming

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I want to return the int value from my Mono class.

```java
int i = counter.map(u -> u.getSeq());
```

I tried this but it show me error as required type: int,
Provided: Mono<java.lang.Object>

this is my Method

```java
public int getNextSequence(String seqName) {
    Mono<CustomSequences> counter = 
        reactiveMongoOperations.findAndModify(
            query(where("_id").is(seqName)),
            new Update().inc("seq", 1),
            options().returnNew(true).upsert(true),
            CustomSequences.class);
    CustomSequences cs = new CustomSequences();
    counter.subscribe(v -> cs.setSeq(v));
    int i = counter.map(u -> u.getSeq());
    return !Objects.isNull(counter) ? i : "1";
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533407/8909235

Comment: @lkatiforis i saw the post but I am need to store it in an integer value and i tried that method in the post but it doesn't work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong..plz help

Comment: @lkatiforis in the code i wanted to subscribe the result as done in the post but it gives an error. `CustomSequences cs=new CustomSequences();` `counter.subscribe(v->cs.setSeq(v));` it cannot set it to the cs because it requires an int and custom sequence is provided.