# Mono<List<Object>> to List<Object> in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am not able to process `Mono<List<Object>>` to `List<Object>`. I have read somewhere that `flatmap` can be used, but I am not able to do that either. I don't want to use `.block()` method for this scenario.

A code example could be:

```java
PagePublisher<Address> someAddressPage = someService.getPagePublisherForAddress();
Mono<List<Address>> addressListMono = 
       Flux.from(someAddressPage.items()).collectList();
```

I need to get `List<Address>` from `Mono<List<Address>>`. The method return type is `List<Address>`.

I am not sure how to go about that and I am relatively new to reactive. Need help in that regard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Mono's content in Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532689/how-to-use-monos-content-in-reactor)

Answer (score 3):

Using `block()` is actually the only way to get the object from a `Mono` when it is emitted. However, you should avoid it at all costs because it defeats the purpose of using the reactive stack given that it actually blocks the thread waiting for the object to be emitted from the `Mono`.

This means that while working with reactive programming you should actually work with `Mono` and `Flux` so that your application is really reactive. The consequence of this is that you must change the return type of your method to return `Mono<List<Address>>` instead.

Comment: I did that earlier but then it response is "scanAvailable=true"

Comment: You will need to add more code so that we can help you further. `scanAvailable=true` may make sense to you but makes no sense to us with so little code you add to your question. So please edit it and add more relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Its impossible to get `List<Address`> from `Mono<List<Address>>`. If the `List` isn't available yet since `Mono` and `Flux` are asynchronous/non-blocking by their nature, you can't get it except by waiting until it comes in and that's what blocking is.

Ideally, your method should return `Mono<List<Address>>` or just `Flux<Address>` and the caller of this method should subscribe to the results. Since you are using Spring Webflux, complete chain should be reactive.

You can subscribe to the `Mono` from the calling method and the Subscriber you pass will get the `List` when it becomes available. E.g.

```
addressListMono.subscribe(
  addressList -> doSomething(addressList), 
  error -> error.printStackTrace(), 
  () -> Console.out.println("completed without a value")
)
```